# Closing a question as duplicate when there are no answers

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I recently posted this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634957/google-drive-share-api-refused-to-display-in-a-frame

Then after some serious Googling on the issue, I accidentally came across: [Can't get Google Drive API share dialog to work when signed into multiple accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664523/cant-get-google-drive-api-share-dialog-to-work-when-signed-into-multiple-accoun)

I offered a bounty on their question because I feel it's better worded than mine and already has some activity. I wanted to close mine and mark as a duplicate of the old question so that I could redirect people there, but was presented with this message:

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

In cases like these, is it appropriate just to delete my question? Should I leave it open? Why *shouldn't* I be able to mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: Two Options: Either you can delete your question if it is duplicate  or you can flag it for duplicate once the original question get accepted answer.

Comment: The questions where asked almost 1 year apart and seeing how the first question does not have a single answer how could it serve any use to the new person asking the question? I think in cases like this it is best to see if the new question can attract any attention and if it gets an accepted answer then close the first question as a duplicate of the second. The person who asked the first question has  not been seen on SO in months so there might be more incentive to answer the new question then the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In cases like these, is it appropriate just to delete my question?

In this case, it appears both the questions are fundamentally asking for the same thing. And as you said, I feel the other question is better worded than yours. So I think it is appropriate to just delete your question.

> Should I leave it open?

Unless you want to rephrase the question or update it, there's no need to leave it open. Just delete your question and keep a track of the new one. Since you started a bounty on it, chances are it will receive an answer shortly.

> Why shouldn't I be able to mark it as a duplicate?

If a question has an answer with a positive score, it means that it has generally been found to be helpful by at least one person, increasing the chances of it being useful to other users who visit through the newer duplicate. If neither of these questions get answered, then we'd finally have a chain of duplicate questions floating around, with none actually answering the question. This feature prevents that from happening.